# Default font size of WPF Run object?

Tags: .net, wpf, font-size

Why default font size of WPF Run object is 12 (on my machine). How can I change it? How can I set to "same as parent"?

```
Run r0 = new Run("hi");
// now r0.fontsize is 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ro.FontSize=(ro.Parent as Textblock).FontSize;

Comment: I want to know where did this default come from?

Comment: The "default" font is the current system font of your current OS. Tahoma is the default system font of Windows XP, on Vista, Windows 7 it is Segoe UI.